# Copy file attributes with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, file-attributes

I'm using the following command to remux audio with ffmpeg (i.e. to copy audio stream to another video file):

```
ffmpeg -i ../../data/1.mp4 -i out.avi -c copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -shortest out.mp4
```

Is there a possibility to also copy the file attributes (timestamp of video file and of frames etc.)?

Comment: Please specify what you mean exactly by the timestamp of the video file. Is it the file creation / modification date? Or possibly EXIF metadata inside the file? And what do you mean with timestamps of video frames? These are copied over to the output file anyway.

Comment: @slhck I mean EXIF metadata inside the file. With timestamps of video frames I mean absolute timestamp of each frame or timestamp of each frame relative to start of video.